# Bootstrap Carousel Links Not Working in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, slider, carousel

I am building a website for my employer at http://graceindustries.com/gracetest

It is built using the Fat Catz template from themesforest/envato which uses Bootstrap 3.0.0.

I have my carousel working as far as animation and resizing and all of that stuff goes. But my problem is with the links.

In internet explorer, the links work fine.

In Google Chrome, only the first carousel item's links work propperly, and nothing happens when I click the subsequent items' links.

The carousel in question is the top most one on the link provided.

The links were working until I added a floating image to each carousel item.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="owl-carousel" id="homeCarousel">
    <div class="item">
        <img style="float:right" style="vertical-align:top" alt="" src="images/portfolio/products/tpass3.png" width="30%" height="auto" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>Lone Worker Safety Solutions</h2>

        <h3>PASS Alarms, Monitoring Systems, & Evacuation Systems</h3>
        <a href="loneworker.html" class="btn btn-sm">
            <i class="icon-right-open-mini"></i> read more
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img style="float:right" style="vertical-align:top" alt="" src="images/portfolio/products/cskit.png" width="30%" height="auto" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>Confined Space Worker Safety</h2>

        <h3>Featuring Our TPASS® 3 Telemetry Kit for Confined Spaces</h3>
        <a href="confinedspace.html" class="btn btn-sm">
            <i class="icon-right-open-mini"></i> read more
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img style="float:right" style="vertical-align:top" alt="" src="images/portfolio/products/gwatch.png" width="30%" height="auto" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>Firefighter Safety</h2>

        <h3>Affordable Firefighter Accountability Systems</h3>
        <a href="firefighter.html" class="btn btn-sm">
            <i class="icon-right-open-mini"></i> read more
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img style="float:right" style="vertical-align:top" alt="" src="images/portfolio/products/ltg.png" width="30%" height="auto" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>Personal Safety Lighting</h2>

        <h3>For Mining, Aviation, Police, and Search & Rescue</h3>
        <a href="lightsafety.html" class="btn btn-sm">
            <i class="icon-right-open-mini"></i> read more
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img style="float:right" style="vertical-align:top" alt="" src="images/portfolio/products/ms1k-glow.png" width="30%" height="auto" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>Prevention Evacuation Systems</h2>

        <h3>Featuring our MS1000X</h3>
        <br>
        <a href="prevention.html" class="btn btn-sm">
            <i class="icon-right-open-mini"></i> read more
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: All Read More links work fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Off topic protip: Remove "click here" from every link and button on your site. It's redundant with the fact that they're links and buttons, and it looks amateurish. Looks great otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever area of bootstrap carousel; take all hyperlinks in such areas are not working on chrome. For example, the left side of slideshow have links and are not working because they exactly are in opposite of slide height. Now try to put hyperlink below the size height of slideshow, even in right side but little below of slideshow that will work. Why it happens I can't guess!